# html form.serialize returns empty string

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, forms, cakephp

I have a file `input` that uploads an image and I would like to send that image to a plugin that crops it.

To convert the `input` file into `base64`, I'm trying to make an ajax request to our php server. If I get the `value` of the `input` via jquery I get "C:/fakepath...", so I am trying to submit a `form` with this `input`.

This `input` is used inside an `element` (reusable component) that is used inside a `form`, so I created a nested `form` that is unrelated to the "parent" `form`.

My problem is that when trying to get the data from the `form` via jquery's `serialize` method, I get an empty `string`.
How do I get the `form` data?

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#picture").change(function(){
            let formData = $('#upload-picture-form').serialize(); //returns ""

            $.ajax({
                url: '/users/getBase64',
                type: 'post',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: formData,
                success: function(data) {
                    alert(data);
                },
                fail: function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>

<section>
    <?php echo $this->Form->input('User.avatar', [
        'label' => false,
        'type' => 'file',
        'class' => 'form-control picture',
        'value' => '',
        'after' => '<br><br><br>',
        'form' => 'upload-picture-form',
    ]); ?>
</section>

<?php 
    echo $this->Form->create('User', [
        'id' => 'upload-picture-form',
        'type' => 'get',
        'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data',
        'action' => 'getBase64'
    ]);
    echo $this->Form->end();
?>
```

html output structure:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
    ... (divs, fieldsets, sections)
    <script>...</script> (see above)
    <form action="/users/getBase64" id="upload-picture-form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="get" accept-charset="utf-8"></form>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: `so I created a nested form that is unrelated to the "parent" form` this would be a problem - you cannot have nested forms. The browser's HTML renderer will remove the inner form and place it outside of the parent. Check the actual rendered source to verify this is happening, as it may be your problem. If this is not the case, please add the full rendered form(s) to the question, not the PHP which generates them

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, placing the inner form ouside the parent would be totally fine in this case. I give the input the "form" attribute to link it to the 2nd form.

Comment: I just checked and the form was not placed ouside the parent form.

Comment: `placing the inner form ouside the parent would be totally fine in this case. I give the input the "form" attribute to link it to the 2nd form.` I'm unfamiliar with CakePHP, so I don't know if that is a feature of that framework, however in plain HTML, which is what your page will be rendered to, nested forms will not, and cannot work. This is why I asked for an example of the HTML output.

Comment: I added the html output structure.
The entire element is inside the parent form, is there any way I can post form data inside it?

Comment: Thank you for adding the HTML. As I have mentioned above, that's a nested form which is invalid HTML. The browser will be removing the inner `<form>`, as you can see if you inspect the DOM in [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/x0y3nt6b/). To fix your problem you need to change your HTML so that the forms are not nested.

Comment: Thanks for the info, is there a way I can do this from inside my element file? So I don't need to copy this for all pages that use this form?

Comment: You could write the form data to a view block, and output that block elsewhere, in your layout, or in the templates that are using the element. **https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views.html#using-view-blocks**